# how to load Text file Thorn(þ) delimited into sql-server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

I have text file something like this

```
col1þcol2þcol3þcol4
aaaþbbbþcccþddd
xxxþyyyþzzzþabs
123þtyehþyetþethrr
```

i tried loading into sql-server using ssis package [after following steps from  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388031/how-to-read-a-flatfile-with-lowercase-thorn-as-the-delimiter) but i couldn't find solution,could somebody guide me in my execution

The Package fails :

here's snap shot from program execution

```
[Flat File Source [8]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column:<column namesss>
```

it outputs like this

[image]

the changes i tried making: like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say you tried using the steps from another answer, but you don't actually tell us what happened when you followed those steps. Did you get an error? If so, what was the error? Did the import happen but have incorrect data?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever when i try on a sample file i get output like i shown in image but when executed on a large file (with 10 big column names+2000 rows) it gives error?

Comment: Based on your column name, it appears you don't have the columns defined in the Connection Manager. Pop a screenshot of the tabs from the Flat File Connection Manager and a row or two of sample data and I can take a look

Comment: @billinkc : iadded details from connection manager

Comment: Ha. My favorite emoticon character.  :-þ

Comment: @RBarryYoung: that's nice !! but could you help me fix this sir ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi Sure, OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a flatfile with lowercase thorn as the delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388031/how-to-read-a-flatfile-with-lowercase-thorn-as-the-delimiter)

Comment: As @RBarryYoung has pointed out in his answer, you don't have columns defined because you don't have the thorn delimiter specified. It's reading your data as one big column. That said, this falls back to being a duplicate of the question you're working through

Comment: thank you @billinkc i figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Change thorn to be your *column* delimiter, not your Row delimiter.  Then change your row delimiter to be line break (presumably).

To do any more we'll need to see your table definitions and the rest of your package definition, particularly the column assignments.

Comment: thank you!! i'm working on it,sample text is nicely executed theres another big text file with "þ" delimiter i need to do that