# SSIS Unknow delimiter Encountered

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am currently working on a ssis project i have a data like this

```
col1þcol2þcol3þcol4
```

i have followed steps from here [How to read a flatfile with lowercase thorn as the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388031/how-to-read-a-flatfile-with-lowercase-thorn-as-the-delimiter)

but the data looks like this ?

`col1Ã¾col2Ã¾col3Ã¾col4` on loading in ssis Flat file connection manager !

What should be delimiter in this case ?

Comment: Maybe you can try this kind on solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653995/split-a-single-column-of-data-with-comma-delimiters-into-multiple-columns-in-ssi/19658817#19658817. Just replace the Split(',') with Split('Ã¾'). See if that works.

Comment: doesn't help ! i need to do it in flat file connection manager ! when i give `þ` it doesn't take and return me this `col1Ã¾col2Ã¾col3Ã¾col4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`þ` is a thorn delimiter

then you need to change the xml code (goto view-->code)

`DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_"`

or as said by @jayvee paste  `þ`  or try pasting `Ã¾`

Answer (score 2):

The column delimiter drop down menu in the connection manager just lists the most common options but you can paste whatever character you need, even if it's not on the list. 
You can then just paste þ and it should work.

Comment: is it still showing col1Ã¾col2Ã¾col3Ã¾col4? if so, at what point do you detect the wrong data?