# Text Qualifier þ (thorn) in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, file, ssis

I need to load a file into SQL server where Icelandic thorn (þ) (it comes by pressing Alt+0254) is used as a text qualifier. I have given þ as text qualifier in SSIS flat file connection manager but SSIS is not recognizing it and it is considering þ also as data. I am not sure how I can proceed with this. Help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Alternate [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778719/ssis-unknow-delimiter-encountered) approaches

Comment: @billinkc I have read the other thread. That question is regarding þ as a delimiter. But this question is related with þ as a text qualifier.

Comment: Apologies, hadn't had tea yet. I *think* you're still going to be going down the same route though, assigning the character code except instead of the column delimiter, it'll be text qualifier. Testing now

Comment: Yup, same approach, just different field that you specify with the thorn. That enough to go on or you need a formal answer?

Comment: Hi billinkc,apologies for extremely late reply. I was unable to do this due to time crunch and had to modifiy the delimiter. Thanks for the reply.