ssis ragged right with whitespace delimiter
Working with legacy software which generates files. This one is a ragged right file that is also fixed width, except since the last line doesn't have the delimiter it's 2 characters short and the last record is skipped if I use fixed width, even though I ignore that column.
The problem with the ragged right solution is that the delimiter is 'F'. I have names in my records which occasionally contain the letter F, which means I can't define the delimiter as just F.
Luckily, the first column for every single record is '01D' and in testing in notepad, if I separate out each record by 'F 01D' that's unique and works. Unfortunately visual studios doesn't recognize that, I believe because of the space. I don't see why it wouldn't recognize spaces as valid characters in a delimiter, but I can't get it to work. I've tried escaping it with 'F\ 01D', I've tried using hex with 'F0x2001D'
Another possible solution but has similar issues is that if I can define the header delimiter as '2õ (plus 16 spaces)' that'll make the F delimiter appear on the left instead of the right and the last record will have enough characters to not be skipped. But, if I simply copy paste from the file into the header delimiter, it claims it can't find the delimiter in the file (same solutions tried above also don't work)
Some odd behavior I noticed. If I set the ragged right row delimiter to 'F ' it will identify one place in the file where that occurs. A comment field which states "USE ALL OF THE AVAILABLE SUPPLY" around 29,000 characters into the file. It's the first occurrence of 'F ' which is preceded by a non space character, though it is far from the only one and all latter occurrences aren't recognized.

I think you have the hex incorrect https://stackoverflow.com/a/63140619/181965 A compound delimiter would take the form of "_x001D__x0047_" assuming I looked up the ascii values correctly

x0047 I think is 'G', not entirely sure what x001D is (is that you adding the 01D which should be on the end?) 20 is hex for the space character, and indeed I mixed up ascii and hex when I tried 0x20 which is the ascii for a space.
I tried a few different hex characters and couldn't get any of them to be recognized. Is there a setting or something to enable them?

As noted in the answer and then in the reference in the answer, using custom delimiters like this is outside what the design tools support but are capabilities of the tool. The format of arbitrary delimiter is the hex value prefixed and suffixed with under scores so _x0000_ is one value, a pair is _x0000__x0001_ a trio, never tried, would be _x0000__x0001__x0002_ Replace the final two "digits" with  the hex equivalent of their ascii value

A hex editor, like xvi32, is an essential if rarely used tool in my ETL toolkit. Crack open the file, confirm the delimiters are what you think they are and it nicely shows you the hex value to patch into your package.

It was indeed a null character. So the whole thing in ascii should be x0046__x0000__x0030__x0031 but that doesn't work. Even a single ascii character doesn't work. Also tried directly editing the .conmgr file and it can no longer load once I launch VS, Error loading 'Flat File Connection Manager.conmgr' : Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0011008
