# Cannot update separator column to flat file destination

Tags: ssis

I need to export data from an ole db source to a csv file in utf-8 with the semicolon as a column separator. When I change the column separator in the connection manager, SSIS does not record the change. I see that it remains on the comma separator and that my changes are not saved. Why?
Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

When you first create a flat file connection manager, you pick the delimiter. If you want to change the delimiter, you need to update all the references which is header row (optional) + all the columns minus the last one

[image]

[image]

In the above, you can see that *if* I had a header row, I'd need to update the "Header row delimiter" which I don't have for this example. And then for all the columns in the Advanced tab, I have to update the "ColumnDelimiter" to be the new delimiter.

It can be helpful to do a search and replace on these as I show in [How to read a flatfile with lowercase thorn as the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388031/how-to-read-a-flatfile-with-lowercase-thorn-as-the-delimiter/20390353#20390353) but make sure you have the package in source control lest you break it but good.